# Is there a way to change imageView resource with if/when statement

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to make a program like this : [image]

I tried a bunch of stuff but don't know what to put into the parenthesis of if/when statements.

var y = getResources().getIdentifier("menu", "drawable", getPackageName())

```
    var y1 = getResources().getIdentifier("door1", "drawable", getPackageName())
    var y2 = getResources().getIdentifier("door_inside", "drawable", getPackageName())
    var y3 = getResources().getIdentifier("door_back", "drawable", getPackageName())
    buttonYes.setOnClickListener {
        when (y) {
        y -> imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.door1)
        }
        if (y1 = true) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.door_inside)
        }
        /*
        when (y2) {
            y2 -> imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.door_inside2)
        }
        when (y3) {
            y3 -> imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.door_back2)
        }

         */
    }

    var n = getResources().getIdentifier("menu", "drawable", getPackageName())
    var n1 = getResources().getIdentifier("door1", "drawable", getPackageName())
    var n2 = getResources().getIdentifier("door_back", "drawable", getPackageName())
    var n3 = getResources().getIdentifier("door_inside", "drawable", getPackageName())
    buttonNo.setOnClickListener {
            if (imageView.resources = n) {
            finishAffinity();
            }
            if (drawable=n1) {
               imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.door_back)
            }
        /*
            when(n2) {
                n2 -> imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.door_back2_1)
            }
            when(n3) {
                n3 -> imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.door_inside2_1)
            }

         */
        }
}
```

}

Comment: In kotlin when is switch case like java. I think you misunderstanding it. Please check it: https://superkotlin.com/kotlin-when-statement/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it would be cleaner to build a map of drawables and use that.

```
import your.package.name.R.drawable.*
//...

data class Choice(val choice1: Int, val choice2: Int)

val choicesMap = mapOf(
     door1 to Choice(door_inside, door_back),
     door_inside to Choice(door_further_inside, door1),
     //etc.
 )
```

Then store current Drawable when you apply it and use it to make the choice.

```
var currentImageDrawable = R.drawable.door1

//...

buttonYes.setOnClickListener {
  currentImageDrawable = choicesMap[currentImageDrawable].choice1
  imageView.setImageResource(currentImageDrawable)
}
buttonNo.setOnClickListener {
  currentImageDrawable = choicesMap[currentImageDrawable].choice2
  imageView.setImageResource(currentImageDrawable)
}
```

Comment: That looks very good but I got a few errors.
1.Unresolved reference: imageResource. In line: imageView.imageResource = currentImageDrawable
2.Classifier 'drawable' does not have a companion object. In line: val choicesMap = with(R.drawable) { mapOf(

Comment: Use `setImageResource()` instead of `imageResource =` then. Not sure why that isn't converted by Kotlin. And remove the `with(R.drawable){}`. I thought it could save some repetition, but didn't realize Java statics aren't converted to Companion objects. Instead you can put `import R.drawable.*` at the top of the file to avoid having to type `R.drawable` over and over.

Comment: Ok first error is fixed. When I added import R.drawable.* at he top it says that R is unresolved reference. How do I fix this? Or maybe you could tell me how to convert it to a companion object? I tried it myself but don't get how they work yet. Thanks.

Comment: Prefix R with your package name. Kotlin cannot convert Java static members into a companion object, unfortunately.

Comment: Had to add !! to line: currentImageDrawable = choicesMap[currentImageDrawable]!!.choice1 and the program is working!
Thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
string buttonSequense ="";

buttonYes.setOnClickListener {
  buttonSequense +="yes";
  setImage();
}
buttonNo.setOnClickListener {
  buttonSequense +="no";
  setImage();
}
```

and then setImage method:

```
public void setImage(){
  if(buttonSequense.equals("yes")){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.door_inside)
  }else if(buttonSequense.equals("yesno")){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.door_back)
  }else if(buttonSequense.equals("yesnonoyesno"))
  //... and so on
}
```